# Why is my Google Maps API being embedded but not displaying on an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So below is my code that I'm using however there is no map being shown on the page. Usually its a css height/width issue but that too has been corrected. Still it just shows an empty div and no map within it.

**My HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY HERE 
&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly">

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**MY JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>

let map;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
zoom: 8
});
}


</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#map { 
width: 100%; 
height: 500px; 
border: 1px solid #000; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a callback to initialize the map. Add `async` to the Maps API script and place it within `<body>` right at the end.

```
  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places&v=weekly"></script>
  </body>
```

Finally make sure that you are using a valid API key and that billing is enabled on your project. Refer to Google's [get started guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started/#overview).

Working jsfiddle from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/6sm9vjew/